# How to pass the width and height parameters before taking snapshot from video

Tags: ios, swift, snapshot

I am taking the snapshot from video it working fine but what i want is before taking snapshot i want to pass custom width and height so i can get different image size rather than the original size.

```
  func loadVideoWithVideoURL(_ videoURL: URL) {
           print("load video url \(videoURL)")
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
        let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time = NSValue(time: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)/2, preferredTimescale: asset.duration.timescale))
        generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: [time]) { [weak self] _, image, _, _, _ in
        if let image = image, let data = UIImage(cgImage: image).pngData() {

       let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
       let uniqueImageName = videoURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
         print("/\(uniqueImageName).JPG")
        let imageURL = urls[0].appendingPathComponent("\(uniqueImageName).jpg")
        let videoURL1 = urls[0].appendingPathComponent("\(uniqueImageName).mov")

//writing data here
       try? data.write(to: imageURL, options: [.atomic])
         }
    }
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: How about resize after taken the image?

Comment: so after taking image i am actually saving in documents directory so before saving to documents directory can we resize the image ?